# CSS not applying, but children

Tags: css, pug

What could be wrong in my CSS for below HTML?

```
div
    div(class="header")
        div(class="team")
            div(class="container")
                div(class="odd")
                    div(class="name")
                        span name
```

CSS:

```
.team .container{
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 10px;
}
.team .container .odd{
    background-color: red;
}
.team .container .name{
    width: 30%;
}
```

However, the only CSS is not applied is `.team .container .odd`. Anyone can suggest what could be wrong?

Comment: Can you post your real html

Comment: Also, check in Chrome Dev Tools if the style is applied and if it's overridden on that class.

Comment: Isn't your html suppose to be tags?
Like <div class="team"> </div>
And, check whether you've linked the external stylesheet if you're using an external style sheet.

Comment: "below HTML" is not HTML.

Comment: The posted structure is in jade, http://html2jade.org/

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: It's my real Jade file and it's a template, so the code is only that short.

Comment: @Leothelion can please help to elaborate which structure could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```css
.team .container {
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
}
.team .container .odd {
  background-color: red;
}
.team .container .name {
  width: 30%;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="header">header
    <div class="team">team
      <div class="container">container
        <div class="odd">odd
          <div class="name">name
            <span>span</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If this works, just check your own css. This is a problem of your existing css then.

Comment: I wonder what is the different between your code and mine? I think you converted my Jade code into HTML?